# In angular2 how do you do an ngEnter on a forms input box so that it calls a function

Tags: angular

In angular2 how do you do an ngEnter on a forms input box so that it calls a function?

I cant seem to get (keyup.enter) working. Also let me know if I need to import any thing.

**This is my form:**

```
<form autocomplete="off" class="bs-component padding-top-20" role="form" #form="ngForm">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <input class="form-control" type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="email" (keyup.enter)="test()" required />                
                        </div>

                        <a class="btn btn-default pink col-xs-12" type="submit" [routerLink]="['/register', {id: email}]">
                        JOIN</a>                                
                    </form>
```

**This is my function in a component:**

```
  test = (): void => {
    console.log("test");
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you need to import is the FormsModule. This shouldn't prevent (keyup.enter) from working though. For what is worth this works for me ([plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/obVHr6ebl3terTlhHheS?p=preview)):

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form>
     <input name="name" [(ngModel)]="form.name" (keyup.enter)="onEnter()">
     <pre>
{{ form | json }}
     </pre>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  form = {
    name: "name"
  };

  onEnter() {
    alert('Enter');
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngSubmit like this

```
<form (ngSubmit)="test()">
```

And your button can be type of submit.